# Vaadin :remove scroll bar from description

Tags: java, scrollbar, vaadin, vaadin8

I have set description for some components using `setDescription("This is the tooltip")`. Some descriptions are English but some other are in persian language. Vaadin shows a scroll bar for persian descriptions:

[image: this is the picture]

How can i remove this scroll bar? English description are fine(don't have scroll bar)

Comment: Have you checked the underlying CSS? I'd imagine it needs to be overridden that way. Something to do with the `overflow` I'd imagine.

Comment: How can i check my description CSS properties?? I use Chrome DevTools and when i want to select the Description to see it's styles, desrctiption hides and i can't select it.! @Jay

Comment: Right click the element in the DOM in Developer Tools and then click ":hover"